Upgraded Highcharts version and getting error as no module
Upgraded Highchart version to 10.3.3 and getting error as:
Module '"highcharts"' has no exported member 'DataPoint'.
Module '"highcharts"' has no exported member 'ElementObject'.
Module '"highcharts"' has no exported member 'IndividualSeriesOptions'.
Module '"highcharts"' has no exported member 'PointEvents'.
Module '"highcharts"' has no exported member 'TreeMapChartSeriesOptions'.

how to overcome this
what can we do to resolve this issue

Make sure that you have removed @types/highcharts dependency ;  You can find more informaiton in the following thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/issues/107
